# How to retreive data as a 2d matrix?

Tags: python, dataframe

I got a file (.txt) containing data such as this sort:

```
Y=[]; 
Y=[Y ;0.178,0.745,0.247,] ; 
Y=[Y ;0.237,0.932,0.347,] ; 
Y=[Y ;0.555,0.666,0.777,] ; 
     .
     .
     .
```

I want to extract the data as a 2d matrix like:

```
array([[0.178,0.745,0.247],        
       [0.237,0.932,0.347],        
       [ 0.555,0.666,0.777],               
                .               
                .               
                .       
       ])
```

I would appreciate any help. And thanks

Comment: This is a matlab file. It might be easier to evaluate this in Matlab/Octave, and store the result `Y` in a dat file. Numpy can read such files.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is a Matlab file, but I'm not familiarized with it, I use Matplotlib instead this is why I need to extract this data to plot it

Comment: you don't need to *plot* it with Matlab, but likely it is better to calculate the entire matrix and store it in a file with matlab.

Comment: The file is so big, what do you mean by "calculate the entire matrix"?
I don't have the Matlab software installed.

Comment: you don't need that. Octave is a free open-source alternative for Matlab.

Comment: Did Octave online work?

Comment: on a debian system it can simply be installed with `apt-get install octave`

Comment: I have Windows10, I use jupyter notebook, it is possible to install it via there (like `pip install octave`)

Comment: no, since it is not a Python package. That being said, I'm happy not to have used Windows in the last 10 years, so I don't now if you still have to download software to install it.

Comment: I search for Octave and I see that I have the ability to work with it online without installing it, is this doable with my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```python
nn = []
with open("log.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        n = re.sub(r'[^\,\.0-9]', '', line).split(',')
        if len(n) <= 2:
            continue
        nn.append(n[:-1])
nn = np.array(nn, dtype=float)
print(nn)
```

upd: you should have mentioned it's matlab. Never worked with it, but pretty sure there should be some python tool to read matlab data

Comment: Thank you for answering. 

The code worked if I uncomment the commented lines but my file is so big, I cannot copy past it in the same cell.
 
How in the code can I import the file (like: `with open('Data.txt') as file:`)

Comment: Just like that:
`with open("log.txt") as infile:\n    for line in infile:\n        do_something_with(line)`


But if your file is really large, than list type that is used for nn can be sub-optimal.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with that new line, to be more clear.
And thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.